# Modifying search scoring algorithm

Tags: search, sorting

Is there any way to tweak the way search score is calculated? For example, I would like words in the title field to be scored higher than the same terms in other fields.

Comment: I can't seem to find anything on the technicals, but how is the whole "best-match to worst-match" thing calculated? For example, if I was to have, an entry with the title "Top Trees" then "Top Trees" I would expect to be a "best-match"?

Comment: Hi Chris, would you mind splitting these into two separate questions? You're more likely to get a good response to your second question that way.

Answer (score 3):

Seems to be the new standard since version 2.2.2582:

"Entry and category search results now place a 5X weight on search term matches within Title fields."