# Score order in search results

Tags: search

I'm building a site and getting some odd search results.

For example, searching against the term 'Gibraltar' returns an entry with four mentions of the term in it's content first, whilst an entry with 'Gibraltar' in the title and 10 instances in the body is returned second.

I am returning the results paginated, ie:

```
{% paginate craft.entries.search( '*' ~ query ~ '*' ).limit(10).order('score') as entries %}
```

Any thoughts why this might be happening? I came across this issue reported last year at [Search order "Score" criteria](https://craftcms.stackexchange.com/questions/2376/search-order-score-criteria) - seems to be the same issue.

Cole

Comment: Of the top of my head: shouldn't it be `.order('score DESC')`, because you want the highest score first?

Comment: Hmm, according to the docs, it shouldn't :)

Comment: Thanks @PaulVerheul - had tried that but throws an error