# Modifying the search order “Score” criteria

Tags: search

I'm a Craft newbie, just searching for something and spotted this related post [Search order "Score" criteria](https://craftcms.stackexchange.com/questions/2376/search-order-score-criteria/13160?noredirect=1#comment17925_13160)

What I would like to know, is there a way to add a Modifier value to a field, like LOW Search does for EE?

For example; lets imagine we want trees listed first.

We would add a 'keyword' field, and a modifier value too help ensure a far higher score than any other fields, possibly including the title.

So an entry with the words 'Top Trees' in our 'keyword' field would trump all other entries containing the words 'Top Trees'.

Answer (score 1):

There currently isn't a native way to do this, and I'm not sure it'd be that easy for a plugin to easily pull off either, since there currently aren't any [search related events](https://craftcms.com/docs/plugins/events-reference) exposed in Craft.

Probably worth adding a [feature request](http://feedback.craftcms.com/search?filter=ideas&query=search) for, though!